# How do you access Content of an Iframe using GWT?

Tags: gwt, iframe

I have a HiddenIframe that i created in GWT which gets response from a post.
OnBrowsewerevent() i try to introspect the contents of Iframe for a error code or success.

When i access the Iframe via GWT, I can access it but innerHTML method always null

I write a JSNI method

```
private native String getMessage()/*-{
    var e = document.getElementById('my_iframe');
    var html = e.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    return html 
    }-*/;
```

I always get e as null as GetelementbyID is returning null, When i introspect HTMLusing firebug i can see the Iframe with the ID. What is the best way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the GWT specific `$doc` variable, instead of `document`. From the [GWT JSNI documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#writing):

> When accessing the browser's window and document objects from JSNI, you must reference them as $wnd and $doc, respectively. Your compiled script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd and $doc are automatically initialized to correctly refer to the host page's window and document.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work after changing it.:-(, I think the basic question i has is - what is recomended in terms of accessing Iframe content form GWT , anything in GWt that can do the magic wihout using JSNI?

Comment: Which browser(s) are you using?